# conda: "command not found" error but package exists?

Tags: conda

I'm currently learning conda, and I'm kind of confused about the `--version` command. I did `conda list` and got a list of all the packages in my environment. Since all the packages are in my environment, `--version` should work for all of them, right? But `--version` only works for the first package in the list. Say these are the packages given by `conda list`:

```
fastqc
font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono
fontconfig
```

Only `fastq --version` would give me the version. If I did, say, `fontconfig --version` it would produce this error:

```
-bash: fontconfig: command not found
```

Does anyone know why `--version` only works for the 1st package in the list of packages? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since all the packages are in my environment, --version should work for all of them, right?

No. `--version` only works for conda itself showing the conda version. The reason it works for fastq as well is that you probably have another fastq installation on your machine. You can find this out by the which command: `which fastq`. Similarly `which fastconfig` should not give a result. Conda list already shows the versions (at least for me it does). If you want to filter for a specific package I'd just grep:
`conda list | grep fastconfig`

Comment: Note that `conda list` accepts a positional regex argument - no need for `grep`. E.g., `conda list fontconfig` or `conda list '^(fastqc|fontconfig)$'` are valid and don't filter out the header info like using `grep`. Also, I still find the wording here slightly confusing. `--version` is an argument that many CLIs implement - saying that it "*only works for conda*" is kind of weird. The reason why it works for `fastqc` is that `fastqc` has a CLI that implements that argument - I don't see why you conclude it must be installed elsewhere.